# Wide to long problems with multiple variables R

Tags: r

I know this problem has been widely discussed in stackoverflow, but I still can't figure it out.
I have a dataset like the following with two variables IC and T; 4 between-subject factors (A, B, C, D) and two within-subject factors (1,2). I want to convert this dataset to a longformat with one ID column, one column for specification which betwee-subject factor it is, one column for the within variable and two columns for each of the value-variables IC and T.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID IC_A_1 IC_A_2 IC_B_1 IC_B_2 IC_C_1 IC_C_2 IC_D_1 IC_D_2 T_A_1 T_A_2 T_B_1 T_B_2 T_C_1 T_C_2 T_D_1 T_D_2  
1 1 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 3 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA 5 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA 3 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA 5 7 NA NA NA NA
4 NA NA 2 1 NA NA NA NA NA NA 5 5 NA NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA NA 3 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 4 NA NA
6 NA NA NA NA 2 3 NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 4 NA NA
7 NA NA NA NA NA NA 4 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA 6 7
8 NA NA NA NA NA NA 4 7 NA NA NA NA NA NA 4 2
")
```

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

Can this give you the desired output?

```
out <- reshape(
  setNames(df, sub("_", ".", names(df))),
  direction = "long",
  idvar = "ID",
  varying = -1
)
```

such that

```
      ID time IC  T
1.A_1  1  A_1  1  2
2.A_1  2  A_1  3  5
3.A_1  3  A_1 NA NA
4.A_1  4  A_1 NA NA
5.A_1  5  A_1 NA NA
6.A_1  6  A_1 NA NA
7.A_1  7  A_1 NA NA
8.A_1  8  A_1 NA NA
1.A_2  1  A_2  2  5
2.A_2  2  A_2  4  5
3.A_2  3  A_2 NA NA
4.A_2  4  A_2 NA NA
5.A_2  5  A_2 NA NA
6.A_2  6  A_2 NA NA
7.A_2  7  A_2 NA NA
8.A_2  8  A_2 NA NA
1.B_1  1  B_1 NA NA
2.B_1  2  B_1 NA NA
3.B_1  3  B_1  3  5
4.B_1  4  B_1  2  5
5.B_1  5  B_1 NA NA
6.B_1  6  B_1 NA NA
7.B_1  7  B_1 NA NA
8.B_1  8  B_1 NA NA
1.B_2  1  B_2 NA NA
2.B_2  2  B_2 NA NA
3.B_2  3  B_2  4  7
4.B_2  4  B_2  1  5
5.B_2  5  B_2 NA NA
6.B_2  6  B_2 NA NA
7.B_2  7  B_2 NA NA
8.B_2  8  B_2 NA NA
1.C_1  1  C_1 NA NA
2.C_1  2  C_1 NA NA
3.C_1  3  C_1 NA NA
4.C_1  4  C_1 NA NA
5.C_1  5  C_1  3  3
6.C_1  6  C_1  2  3
7.C_1  7  C_1 NA NA
8.C_1  8  C_1 NA NA
1.C_2  1  C_2 NA NA
2.C_2  2  C_2 NA NA
3.C_2  3  C_2 NA NA
4.C_2  4  C_2 NA NA
5.C_2  5  C_2  3  4
6.C_2  6  C_2  3  4
7.C_2  7  C_2 NA NA
8.C_2  8  C_2 NA NA
1.D_1  1  D_1 NA NA
2.D_1  2  D_1 NA NA
3.D_1  3  D_1 NA NA
4.D_1  4  D_1 NA NA
5.D_1  5  D_1 NA NA
6.D_1  6  D_1 NA NA
7.D_1  7  D_1  4  6
8.D_1  8  D_1  4  4
1.D_2  1  D_2 NA NA
2.D_2  2  D_2 NA NA
3.D_2  3  D_2 NA NA
4.D_2  4  D_2 NA NA
5.D_2  5  D_2 NA NA
6.D_2  6  D_2 NA NA
7.D_2  7  D_2  5  7
8.D_2  8  D_2  7  2
```

---

If you want to remove rows with `NA`s, you can try

```
> na.omit(out)
      ID time IC T
1.A_1  1  A_1  1 2
2.A_1  2  A_1  3 5
1.A_2  1  A_2  2 5
2.A_2  2  A_2  4 5
3.B_1  3  B_1  3 5
4.B_1  4  B_1  2 5
3.B_2  3  B_2  4 7
4.B_2  4  B_2  1 5
5.C_1  5  C_1  3 3
6.C_1  6  C_1  2 3
5.C_2  5  C_2  3 4
6.C_2  6  C_2  3 4
7.D_1  7  D_1  4 6
8.D_1  8  D_1  4 4
7.D_2  7  D_2  5 7
8.D_2  8  D_2  7 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you at least to some extent?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  tidyr::separate(name, into = c("IC_T", "subject_factors", "id"))

# A tibble: 128 x 5
      ID IC_T  subject_factors id    value
   <int> <chr> <chr>           <chr> <int>
 1     1 IC    A               1         1
 2     1 IC    A               2         2
 3     1 IC    B               1        NA
 4     1 IC    B               2        NA
 5     1 IC    C               1        NA
 6     1 IC    C               2        NA
 7     1 IC    D               1        NA
 8     1 IC    D               2        NA
 9     1 T     A               1         2
10     1 T     A               2         5
```